# Direcciones de memoria de variables locales y globales

Tags: c, punteros, gcc

hasta donde sabía cuando un programa es cargado a memoria utiliza 4 segmentos: texto, datos, pila, y heap. Las variables globales se graban en el segmento de datos mientras que las variables locales en la pila. Además, por teoría se sabe que las direcciones del segmento de datos deben ser inferiores a las de la pila; pero no veo eso al ejecutar este pequeño programa

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int a = 10;

void main( void ) {
  int b = 5;

  printf( "%p %p", &a, &b );
}
```

Lo que veo como salida es es la variable global a esta siendo almacenada en `0x100402010` mientras que b en `0xffffcc0c`. Pero obviamente `0x100402010` es mayor que `0xffffcc0c`, lo que parece contradecir, según la teoría, la forma en que la memoria asignada a un programa está organizada. ¿Por qué la dirección de b (que está en la pila) es menor? ¿O acaso %p no me permite ver la dirección de memoria completa y sólo me deja ver los 4 últimos bytes? OJO: Estoy usando C, gcc, y Win-64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Por qué la dirección de b (que está en la pila) es menor?

El estándar del lenguaje no determina dónde debe almacenarse cada variable. Eso es algo que queda a discrección de la tupla compilador-Sistema Operativo. Si el Sistema Operativo impone una determinada organización de la memoria el compilador no tiene más remedio que apechugar con ello.

En cualquier caso no veo qué ventajas puede proporcionar que una región de memoria se encuentre antes que otra... o al revés.

> ¿O acaso %p no me permite ver la dirección de memoria completa y sólo me deja ver los 4 últimos bytes?

Un byte tiene un tamaño típico de 8 bits... en hexadecimal un byte ocupa exactamente un dígito (0..F). Las direcciones que indicas son de 64 bits y prueba de ello son los 8 dígitos que tienen (8 dígitos * 8 bits por dígito = 64 bits)

Comment: En cuanto a lo último, no es cierto que un caracter hexadecimal ocupa un byte. En un byte caben dos caracteres hexadecimales. Por ejemplo, la dirreccion 0xffffcc0c puede grabarse en 4 bytes, a pesar de tener 8 caracteres hexadecimales. De hecho, acabo de hacer un programa donde se aprecia que el ffffcc0c al ser grabado en un puntero "p" solo ocupa los 4 bytes menos significativos de los 8 que se reservan para el puntero. Los otros 4 bytes se rellenan con ceros.

Comment: @FredyCuenca 1 byte, por defecto, son 8 bytes. En serio. Un entero ocupa tipicamente 4 bytes o 32 bits... haz las cuentas

Comment: @FredyCuenca lo que pasa ea que estás compilando en 64 bits... luego los punteros van a ser de 64 bits

Comment: No entendi bien eferion, ¿dices que con que para representar un byte necesitas un digito hexadecimal?, ¿no seran 2?

Comment: @CodigoFasil si perdona tienes razón... no se en que estaba pensando